# Angular TypeScript - How to push String into Var String

Tags: angular, typescript

My code looks like this;

```
intercept(
    request: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    let token = localStorage.getItem('token'); 
    let newRequest: HttpRequest<any>;
    newRequest = request.clone({
      headers: request.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token),
    });
    console.log(newRequest)
    return next.handle(newRequest);
  }
```

And my headers that sends to backend looks like this;

```
key
: 
"authorization"
value
: 
['Bearer "eyJhbGciOiJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAxLz…eiAQgeeiwwfbJ_gzDb2mI5FPx8WOLWcJaku9cGgcrdORIP6A"']
```

I want to send my headers like;

```
key
: 
"authorization"
value
: 
['Bearer eyJhbGciOiJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAxLz…eiAQgeeiwwfbJ_gzDb2mI5FPx8WOLWcJaku9cGgcrdORIP6A']
```

I know I need to push Bearer into token but how;

```
headers: request.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token),
```

I want to know what is the true piece of code to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TLDR;
`JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('token'));`

You get the string stored in the local Storage, the string is transformed to json and saved as a string (`JSON.stringify`) to local storage. When you read the json-string out, you need to parse the json-string again to get the original string back.

Comment: Aww sure, I was so close to get mad. Thank you!!